# Next-Auth with google gets `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error` error in NextJS App router

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth

## Google OAuth Authentication in Next.js using next-auth is not working

I've set up a Next.js application and I'm trying to implement Google OAuth authentication using the `next-auth` library. Despite following the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/google), I can't seem to get it to work.

### Setup

I created OAuth 2.0 Client credentials on the Google Developer Console. With those credentials, I'm trying to create a login with Google's authentication prompt using `next-auth`.

### API Route

**File path**: `app/(index)/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```js
import NextAuth, { Account, NextAuthOptions, Profile } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_client_id as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_client_secret as string,
        authorization: {
            params: {
              prompt: "consent",
              access_type: "offline",
              response_type: "code"
            }
          },
      }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({account, profile}:{account: Account | null; profile?: Profile | undefined;}) {
        const isAccount = account && profile;
        if (isAccount && account.provider === "google") {
            // return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@example.com");
            return true;
        }
        return true; // Handle other providers differently
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

### Login Component

```js
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          signIn();
        }}
      >
        Sign in
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Issue

When I click the "Sign in" button, page redirects to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error`.
and I get error message:

```
This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405
```

### Question

What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I get the Google OAuth authentication to work in my Next.js application using next-auth?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out. It was because I was following pages/ router guide.
App router guide [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app)

code should look like this:

```js
import NextAuth, { Account, NextAuthOptions, Profile } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_client_id as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_client_secret as string,
        authorization: {
            params: {
              prompt: "consent",
              access_type: "offline",
              response_type: "code"
            }
          },
      }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async signIn({account, profile}:{account: Account | null; profile?: Profile | undefined;}) {
        const isAccount = account && profile
        if (isAccount && account.provider === "google") {
            // return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@example.com")
            return true
          }
        return true // Do different verification for other providers that don't have `email_verified`
    }
  }
})

// export default NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem, follow my solution on Github here:

[ACCESS DENIED SOLVED using MongoDB and Next-auth Solved](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_next_13_ai_prompt_sharing/issues/60#issue-1845115420)